# Checking JAR Usage at the Package Level

Tags: java, jar, classpath

Is there a tool out there that can check if an imported JAR is being used from within a package? Basically I want to remove any unused JARs from a project and I do not want to have to remove each JAR one-by-one and check for possible reference issues for each removed JAR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) will do the trick for you! Configured correctly and given some initial rules it will take jar files in an input directory and output the same jars into the output directory. Java class files that aren't needed won't be included in the output jars and if a jar has no classes left, it's simply removed. The website also includes tons of [examples](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/examples.html).

In addition to doing this, it has a number of great features to help in compacting and obfuscating your final project. The configuration files may seem a bit tricky at first -- but it pays off. In some projects at work, we have final archive sizes that are reduced well over 1000%. How often have you included a library only to use a fraction of the functionality? With a proper setup the final product will only include what's needed.

Comment: Yes, I use ProGuard for this on every build I do - it's an excellent tool!